# Powershell, Invoke-SqlCmd and flushing output

Tags: powershell

How to force Invoke-SqlCmd in Powershell to flush its output? Basically the same question asked at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3060, where Powershell people say it's SQL's problem whereas *"SQL folks say this is an issue with the default powershell output, not their code"*.

Here is a simple demo:

```
Write-Host "Run 1"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentTime;"
#Read-Host -Prompt "press a key..."

Write-Host "Run 2"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentTime;"
```

the output would look like this:

```
Run 1

Run 2
CurrentTime         
-----------         
8/23/2019 9:24:44 AM
8/23/2019 9:24:44 AM
```

whereas I am expecting that the first output is after "Run 1" and before "Run 2". If commenting out the `Read-Host`, the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` get separated but still not what I'm expecting:

```
Run 1

press a key...: 
CurrentTime         
-----------         
8/23/2019 9:22:28 AM

Run 2
8/23/2019 9:22:32 AM
```

So, how to force Invoke-SqlCmd in Powershell to flush its output?

Comment: You can set two variables i.e $run1 = invoke-sql ...... and $run2 = invoke-sql ....| is this what you need?

Comment: @MahmoodShehab, sorry I don't know Powershell that well -- how to output those two variables?

Comment: OK, I will post the it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see your script after modification below:

```
$run1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentTime;" | Out-String;
Write-Host "Run 1 is $run1"
#Read-Host -Prompt "press a key..."
Start-Sleep 2  #To simulate different timing
$run2 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentTime;" | Out-String
Write-Host "Run 2 is $run2"
```

And the output will be,

```
Run 1 is 
CurrentTime          
-----------          
8/23/2019 11:51:47 AM



Run 2 is 
CurrentTime          
-----------          
8/23/2019 11:51:49 AM
```